# Should I save user backend in database in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I'm creating a Django website that supports both local login backend and LDAP login (through `django-auth-ldap`), and maybe more in the future.

I'm getting into Django login and backends sutff and have a couple of questions - mainly **is there any reason Django doesn't keep user creation backend in the database**? Shouldn't user `A` be linked (and by linked I mean a field on `User` model) with the backend `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend` for safety/convince reason?

I'm getting around to creating a custom user model, and was thinking about adding such field. The ability to **unambiguously know which backend was/is used to create/login the user sounds** logically for me, but the fact that Django doesn't have that by default, and that I can't find anything similar on the Internet has me worried that I didn't think of a *really* good reason for why it's done the way it is.

Thanks in advance,
Paweł

Answer (score 0):

Django doesn't need that info. Once the user is authenticated, and django has a User model, it doesn't care what backend authenticated it. The User model data is stored in one source. The User model (whether the default or custom) is consistent and has the same attributes, functionality and behaviour across the entire django project and schema. Nothing in the out-of-the-box django deals with different user models.

You may extend this with AbstractBaseUser, but managing really different users across the same project, especially with the core django modules, is  a strech.

Django uses the User model **a lot**, and you will have to manually locate each place it does, and provide your own router to the correct backend. There is no API for this (like, say, db routers), it's going to be a mess of hacks that will probably even messier with each upgrade.

Django does support, in addition to the custom user model, "authentication backends". Some of the functionality your are looking for is available and exposed with this option, in a formal API. So you probably want to stick with that.
see:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#authentication-backends

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think you understood my question - I tried to edit it to be more clear.

Comment: I think I did. Read the django docs, but to summarise, once the user is authenticated and django got the User model, it doesn't care where it was authenticated from. You are looking for something that in a way is very different from the django architecture. Of course, you can patch everything to anything, but you are not in the framework way of thinking any more.